# VSCode messed up git repository

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code

Is there any probability that VSCode git integration messed up my git repository?
Without any visible reason (no add, no commit, only file editing) at one point all files in git repository folder is marked to add.
"git status" return me all files and folders are deleted, and to re add it all.

If not, what can cause a behaviour like this?

I'm using OSX with VSC and zsh as terminal shell.
The repository is on a ssh mounted folder and all git commands are executed via ssh connected terminal.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Happened to me as well. That was the last day I used it.

Comment: Check you still have a .git subfolder containing the repository. Then it is a case of doing a git fcsk check to ensure your old committed data is still there, and then finding out where you are now, and where your branch heads should be. If some other 'code' has tidied up your file structure and removed your local repo, then its back to the backup for recovery - you do have a backup?

Comment: .git still there.. 
got backup on bitbucket but cannot commit the modified files.. (just copied away, re-cloned the repository and copied and paste the new code... )

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me multiple times as well. Luckily, I `git push` to a remote location regularly, just in case like this.

Sometimes, `git reset .` works just fine, but today, it didn't.
I noticed that the `git branch` returned an empty list, but I still can see remote branches:

```
% git branch
% git branch -r
  origin/main
  ...
```

I tried to checkout the `main` branch but got this error:

```
% git checkout -f -b main origin/main
Updating files: 100% (315/315), done.
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/main': Unable to create '.git/refs/heads/main.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

So after I removed the `main.lock`, the `git checkout -f -b main origin/main` fixed the issue.

Unfortunately, I lost all the staged changes.

As I don't use any other tools for this specific repository, I guess VScode messed up its own git process and removed the `main` branch ref.